# Need function get Duration of Video when upload it in asp core C#

Tags: c#

```
    public void Duration()
    {
        using (ShellObject shell = ShellObject.FromParsingName(@"C:\Users\compu magic\Desktop\imgs\vv.mp4"))
        {
            // alternatively: shell.Properties.GetProperty("System.Media.Duration");
            IShellProperty prop = shell.Properties.System.Media.Duration;
            // Duration will be formatted as 00:44:08
            string duration = prop.FormatForDisplay(PropertyDescriptionFormatOptions.None);
            TimeSpan dd = TimeSpan.Parse(duration);
            var ada = Convert.ToInt32(dd.TotalMilliseconds / 1000);
            Console.WriteLine(ada);
        }
    }
```

I use this function but give me error==> Could not load type 'System.Windows.Size' from assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Comment: You can do it via VLC https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp

Comment: Is WindowsBase present in the references of the project ? f not, try adding it

Comment: thanks i find a soulation